# Counting Inversions Using Merge Sort

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting, program-correctness

In Corman, Introduction To Algorithms, 3rd edition, question 2-4 it asks to count the number of inversions in a list of numbers in $\theta( n \lg n )$ time.  He uses a modified Merge Sort to accomplish this.  However, there is something in his algorithm which seems redundant / unnecessary to me:

```
MERGE-INVERSIONS(A, p, q, r)
n1 = q - p + 1
n2 = r - q
let L[1 ... n1 + 1] and R[1 ... n2 + 1] be new arrays
for i = 1 to n1
    L[i] = A[p + i - 1]
for j = 1 to n2
    R[j] = A[q + j] 
L[n1 + 1] = infinity
R[n2 + 1] = infinity
i = 1
j = 1
inversions = 0
counted = FALSE
for k = p to r
    if counted == FALSE and R[j]  < L[i]
        inversions = inversions + n1 - i + 1
        counted = TRUE
    if L[i] <= R[j] 
        A[k] = L[i]
        i++
    else A[k] = R[j] 
        j++
        counted = FALSE
return inversions
```

The `counted` variable seems redundant to me and I would have written the last for loop as follows:

```
inversions = 0
for k = p to r
    if L[i] <= R[j] 
        A[k] = L[i]
        i++
    else A[k] = R[j] 
        inversions = inversions + n1 - i + 1
        j++
return inversions
```

What am I missing, or is `counted` really unnecessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can show that after every iteration of the `for`-loop in question, `counted` is `FALSE`. Therefore, `inversions = inversions + n1 - i + 1` is executed if and only if `j++` is executed in the same iteration (both are guarded by `R[j] < L[i]`). Since neither `i` nor `j` is changed between evaluation of the two `if` conditions, this implies that your version is equivalent.

> We perform an induction over `k`. Before the loop, `counted` is explicitly set to `FALSE`. In any given iteration, we start (by induction hypothesis) with `counted == FALSE`. If `L[i] <= R[j]`, `counted` is not changed throughout the current iteration. If the opposite is the case, `counted` is first set to `TRUE`, but reset to `FALSE` in the `else` block. For this, we note that the truth value of `R[j] < L[i]` remains unchanged from the first to the second `if`.

I guess the extra block is there for didactic reasons.

Comment: There's something strange going on here.  Your quote shows up pink and blank, except when I hold my mouse over it, then it slowly fades in.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes: That is as intended. It's the spoiler tag, here used to hide details for the sake of self-study.